# E: Unable to locate package libmysql-ruby

Tags: apt, mysql, ruby

I try to install mysql for rails but i know that first must install the package

libmysql-ruby

I do the command

```
E: Unable to locate package libmysql-ruby
```

But It returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysql-ruby
```

I try to do upgrade and update but it same

Comment: Are you sure you are following correct up-to-date instructions for your Ubuntu version? `libmysql-ruby` appears to be a transitional package that has been phased out in 14.04. The new package name seems to be `ruby-mysql`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`libmysql-ruby` appears to be a transitional package that has been phased out: the new package name seems to be `ruby-mysql`. If you are running Ubuntu 14.04 or later you will need to use

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql
```

Comment: Unable to locate package ruby-mysql